# Cross compiling godot as export template for arm

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, godot

I'm encountering difficulties cross-compiling the Godot 3.5.3 source for ARM 32 architecture as an export template. I'm using the following repository for cross-compilation: https://github.com/hiulit/cross-compile-godot-raspberry-pi.

For some reason, even though I follow all the steps outlined in the repository, my Ubuntu system seems to be using the system gcc and g++ for compilation instead of the expected arm-godot-gnueabihf-gcc and arm-godot-gnueabihf-g++ from the toolchain directory (toolchain/bin/), resulting in Godot compiled wrongly

Could someone help me understand why this might be happening and how I can ensure that the correct toolchain is being used for cross-compilation?

I want to get working custom export-template which will allow me to cross compile every godot project for arm (Raspberry pi)

Comment: Please explain what you did, e.g., which commands you ran, show the errors you received and the problems you had.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl you have all commands on https://github.com/hiulit/cross-compile-godot-raspberry-pi link, i am using cross-compile-godot-raspberry-pi.cfg to set directories to my godot source code and toolchain and then i use command ./cross-compile-godot-raspberry-pi --auto to start compiling, but point is that script is not using correct toolchain if im right, u can try to reproduce what i did if u have time, thank you